# How to figure out if user is logout from facebook using fandjango app

Tags: django, django-facebook, fandjango

I am using fandjango app for handling facbook user information. If user is logout from facebook and hit url from same browser, I am getting error
**Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out**.
 Can somebody tell me, how to solve this problem and how to identify if user is log out from facebook or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the facebook object of your request:

```
def view(request):
    if request.facebook and hasattr(request.facebook, 'user') and request.facebook.user is not None:
        // Here you are sure that request.facebook.user is logged in
```

Comment: when user is logged out, you will still able to get request.facebook object. SO from this way we can not identify.